# Style only one anchor link with class applied to li

Tags: css, stylesheet

Struggling with this one but I'm sure it's quite easy!

WordPress is applying a class "current_page_item" to the `<li>` that surrounds my anchor link in my side menu. I want to bold the current page item only.

I have some sub menus being nested like so:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="current_page_item">
        <a>Please bold</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a>Pleas DO NOT bold</a></li>
            <li><a>Pleas DO NOT bold</a></li>
            <li><a>Pleas DO NOT bold</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I just cannot get the 1 link to bold, it bolds every sub link as well.

```
ul.menu li.current_page_item:first-child {font-weight:bold}
```

What CSS do I need? If the class was on the anchor link itself this would be simple but I can't get my head round how to do it.

Comment: your markup is wrong..please correct it first and then apply the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
ul.menu li.current_page_item > a:first-child {font-weight:bold}
```

This will bold the `a` tag directly under `ul.menu li.current_page_item`, no matter how many direct `a` tags you have under it.

**Working Code Snippet:**

```css
ul.menu li.current_page_item > a:first-child {font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="current_page_item">
        <a>Please bold</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a>Pleas DO NOT bold</a>
            <li><a>Pleas DO NOT bold</a>
            <li><a>Pleas DO NOT bold</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `a:first-child` like this

```
.menu li.current_page_item a:first-child{
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ewvsLLn7/)

**NOTE**

all your li's in markup are not closed,so use

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="current_page_item"> <a>Please bold</a></li>
        <li>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a>Pleas DO NOT bold</a></li>
                <li><a>Pleas DO NOT bold</a></li>
                <li><a>Pleas DO NOT bold</a></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry Sajad, this didn't bold anything. Other solution worked but thanks for trying.

Comment: @JamesWilson: that's becz your markup is wrong..!! please check your markup

Comment: Granted the example I typed out wasn't right but the css wasn't working on my WordPress site either so I'm not sure why that was. The fiddle looks good though so thanks again for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support older browsers as well, do this

```
.current_page_item>a{
                    font-weight:bold
                    }
```

This will select the direct child of the `.current_page_item`,which is anchor and make it bold. This is a better approach than first-child because first-child is not supported in older browsers. **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kvppmsfd/1/)**

**Note**: use this if you want to make all the anchors which are direct children of `.current_page_item`, else if you just want the first one to be bold use

```
ul.menu li.current_page_item > a:first-child {font-weight:bold}
```

As explained by [rahul](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28409877/3556874). But still If you have multiple anchors and you need to make them bold, you will end up using `first-child, nth-child, last-child,etc` i would suggest using a class for making element bold(some thing like `class='bold'`), or as I have shown above